# postgres new schema to inherit permissions for a user

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a created read only user with below commands

```
CREATE ROLE read_only WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password' 
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL 
'infinity';
```

Then I gave select permision

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO read_only;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to read_only;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO 
read_only;
```

My requirement is whenever there is a new schema added it should inherit the permissions for read_only user. Currently I manually assign these permissions for new schema.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that automatically, you will have to continue doing that explicitly.